# Failed to start PostgreSQL database server. -- all of the sudden

Tags: arch-linux, postgresql

All of the sudden postgresql has broken down:

```
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-11-19 11:09:41 ICT; 8s ago
  Process: 20873 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGROOT}/data (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 19 11:09:40 my_notebook systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
Nov 19 11:09:41 my_notebook systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 19 11:09:41 my_notebook systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
Nov 19 11:09:41 my_notebook systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 19 11:09:41 my_notebook systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

What can be the reason?

Comment: any additional logs would be useful; postgres logs?